# Install Nibabel for Python 3

Tags: python3

How can I get the Nibabel module for Python 3?  Only the Nibabel module for Python 2 is in the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier, this is not in the repositories, but you can install is yourself. (I tested this on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04).

A prerequisite is [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numpy).  If you don't have this for Python3, then open a terminal (<kbd>CTL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

## Easy Way (using PIP)

If you don't have PIP for Python 3, you can get it on Ubuntu 14.04 by doing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and on Ubuntu 12.04, by doing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

Now, to install Nibabel, do

```
sudo pip3 install nibabel
```

Done.

## Hard Way (build from source)

We'll use git to download Nibabel, so type this command

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Download nibabel by typing

```
git clone https://github.com/nipy/nibabel.git
```

then move to the new `nibabel` directory by doing

```
cd nibabel
```

At this point, you can do `sudo python3 setup.py install`, but it's better to use the program [`checkinstall`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-checkinstall-build-packages-source) which will make it easier to uninstall the package if you need to.  So type

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

and install nibabel with

```
sudo checkinstall python3 setup.py install
```

If it asks `Should I create a default set of package docs? [y]:`, hit <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

When it says `Please write a description for the package`, you can type whatever (I typed "`python3-nibabel`") and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> .

When it says `This package will be built according to these values:`, hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If it asks `Do you want me to list them?  [n]:`, hit <kbd>N</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If it asks `Should I exclude them from the package? ...`, hit <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

You should be done.  Type `python3`, then `import nibabel` to check that it worked.  If you need to uninstall it, open a terminal and type: `sudo apt-get remove nibabel`.